# Issue with Visibility setting of a control inside a group box WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have my groupbox defined inside a window as follows

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid Name="gridMain">
        <GroupBox x:Name="grp" Header="Group" Margin="0,71,0,0">
            <Grid Margin="0,69,0,0" x:Name="gridmain">
                <CheckBox x:Name="ChkShow" Content="Hide Controls" IsChecked="True" Checked="ChkShow_Checked" Unchecked="ChkShow_Unchecked" Margin="27,52,76,38"></CheckBox>
                <Label x:Name="lblUsername" Content="Username" Margin="21,10,107,68" Visibility="Hidden"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This is my code to show/hide the control

```
private void ChkShow_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lblUsername.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}

private void ChkShow_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lblUsername.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

But I am unable to find the control it is getting as null so how can I over come this issue

Comment: Make sure above `Group-box` not is inside any `contentcontrol` or `template`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about order.

The `CheckBox` is created first. The event handlers are attached and the value is set to `True`. The event handler fires and tries to call the not-yet-created `Label`. Hence the `Label` is having the value `null`.

If you move the label to above the `CheckBox` it does work. It will also work if you would attach the event handlers later on, for example in the `OnLoad` method.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. :)

Comment: Yeah if its because of order then best practice is  attach event on onLoad event of window.

Comment: Too many problems with WPF in design not adjusting as per the screen resolution :( need manually adjust the margins, not so cool as Win Forms

Comment: WPF should work with automatic scaling, but it can be a pain indeed.

Comment: @Dotnet WPF is more kool compare to .. win forms .. you can do whatever you want to do..but yeah it can be painful while scaling ..

Answer (score 1):

I faced a same issue.
Actually checkbox event fire before label control initialize.

So you need to check first control is initialized first, means control not equal to null.

Or you can directly set visibility using binding(need bool to visibility converter) or you can set visibility using data trigger.

```
<Label x:Name="lblUsername" Content="Username" Margin="21,10,107,68" Visibility="{Binding path=IsChecked, ElementName=ChkShow, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"></Label>
```

Here is link for bool to visible converter http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html